# How do I limit API requests to one per user at the same time?

Tags: php, laravel, api, cron-task

I have created a site for social marketing.
Services are provided by an API.
When the user requests the service, more than one request is sent by the API.
How to make it request the service only once?

```
public function cron(){
    $orders = Order::where('status', 'Pending')->where('service_no', '!=', 0)->get();
    $api = ApiSetting::first();
    foreach ($orders as $order){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api->url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "key=".$api->key."&action=add&service=".$order->service_no."&link=".$order->link."&quantity=".$order->quantity);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
        $item = json_decode($server_output);
        $order->order_no = $item->order;
        $order->save;
        curl_close ($ch);
    }
}

public function cronn(){
    $orders = Order::where('order_no', '!=', 0)->where('service_no', '!=', 0)->get();
    $api = ApiSetting::first();
    foreach ($orders as $order){
        $new_curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($new_curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api->url);
        curl_setopt($new_curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($new_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "key=".$api->key."&action=status&order=".$order->order_no);
        curl_setopt($new_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $server_output = curl_exec ($new_curl);
        $item = json_decode($server_output);
        $order->start_count = $item->start_count;
        $order->remains = $item->remains;
        $order->status = $item->status;
        $order->save;
        curl_close ($new_curl);
    }
}
```

Comment: no idea what you are asking, could you add some more explination

Comment: Added full stops so sentences don't run in.  Revised title to provide relevant info about the issue.